# Call the SSRS report in button click and need to get the output as PDF file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had an grid view where I had placed an link button to print an report. In this button click event I need to call the SSRS report and need to get the output as PDF file.

I had used this below code,the code is running fine, but I'm unable to see the prompt to open/save pdf file.

```
   protected void btnAuthenticateAndPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
     {
       try
        {

        //Getting Values from grid
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
        Label lbOrderID = row.FindControl("lbOrderID") as Label;
        int OrderId = Convert.ToInt32(lbOrderID.Text);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Get_PODetails", con);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MPDI_ID", OrderId);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "PO");
        if (ds.Tables["PO"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lblPOId.Text=ds.Tables["PO"].Rows[0]["MPDI_ID"].ToString();
            lblVendid.Text = ds.Tables["PO"].Rows[0]["MVDI_ID"].ToString();
            lblBranch.Text = ds.Tables["PO"].Rows[0]["MBRI_ID"].ToString();
            lblDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables["PO"].Rows[0]["MPDI_Date"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        }

        //SSRS Report Print
        rs = new RSWebService.ReportingService2005();
        rsExec = new REWebService.ReportExecutionService();
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        rsExec.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        rs.Url = "http://localhost/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx";
        rsExec.Url = "http://localhost/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx";
        byte[] Sendresults = null;
        byte[] bytes = null;
        string historyID = null;
        string deviceInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";
        string format = "PDF";
        string encoding = null;
        string mimeType = null;
        string extension = null;
        REWebService.Warning[] warnings = null;
        string[] streamIDs = null;
        string _reportName = @"/FIMO GOF Assets Reports/PURCHASE ORDER";
        REWebService.ExecutionInfo ei = rsExec.LoadReport(_reportName, historyID);
        REWebService.ParameterValue[] parameters = new REWebService.ParameterValue[4];
        parameters[0] = new REWebService.ParameterValue();
        parameters[0].Name = "MVDI_ID";
        parameters[0].Value = lblVendid.Text;
        parameters[1] = new REWebService.ParameterValue();
        parameters[1].Name = "MBRI_ID";
        parameters[1].Value = lblBranch.Text;
        parameters[2] = new REWebService.ParameterValue();
        parameters[2].Name = "MPDI_Date";
        parameters[2].Value = lblDate.Text;
        parameters[3] = new REWebService.ParameterValue();
        parameters[3].Name = "ReportParameter1";
        parameters[3].Value = lblPOId.Text;
        rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");
        Sendresults = rsExec.Render(format, deviceInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Sendresults);


        //To create a PDF
        if (format == "PDF")
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=output.pdf");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", Sendresults.Length.ToString());
        }
        Response.OutputStream.Write(Sendresults, 0, Sendresults.Length);
        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        Response.OutputStream.Close();

      }
       catch(Exception Ex)
       {
        throw Ex;
        }
   }
```

Comment: I threw together a button click that looks like this-

`protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/txt";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=output.pdf");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", "1");
        Response.OutputStream.Write(new byte[] { 255 }, 0, 1);
        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        Response.OutputStream.Close();
    }
}`

And it's giving me a popup when I click through- have you tried setting a breakpoint to make sure your code is getting called?

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but where are we assigning the byte[] Sendresults to this code to flush the report.?and also do we need to add any particular namespaces /assemblies..?

Comment: @vinay I would try chrispy's comment and see if the window pops up for you.  It could be you have another issue which is preventing the popup which will be more clear when you adapt chrisp's code to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL access, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154040(v=sql.105).aspx

```
http://<Server Name>/reportserver?/Sales/YearlySalesSummary&rs:Format=PDF&rs:Command=Render
```