# SSRS Automatically iterate through multiple parameters and save each as PDF

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, reporting-services

Environment: SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition. I have a report that has Param1 (State) and Param2 (County).  I need to figure out how to use something to automatically iterate through each county in each state, and save the county level reports as seperate PDFs.  This is a SQL Server VM in Azure. Hoping there is something in SSIS, SSRS or worst case C# where I can make this work.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a way you can call reports from C#. You specify the URL, the parameters, and the type (pdf in this case).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14058610/2850543 and http://sandeep-aparajit.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-execute-and-save-ssrs-report.html

Comment: You may know (since you mentioned standard edition) that Enterprise Edition has a feature called Data-Driven Subscriptions which does exactly this. It may be worth doing the math on the license cost vs. the custom development cost.

Comment: This is also completely doable via SSIS - you basically just use a ForEach Loop to pass through the parameters and then a Script Task to run the report.  https://msbiblog.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/run-and-export-ssrs-reports-from-ssis-sql-server-2005/ has a quick walkthrough and a sample SSIS package you can use

Answer (score 1):

The exact functionality is not directly supported. You could either create a device extension (overkill) or look at third party libraries to **merge the output of multiple reports**.

**Edit:**

I just re-read your keyword - **seperate PDFs**. To automate, I thought you could initially use the subscription feature of enterprise version ssrs with optional snapshots to save processing. However, how do you manage access and dispersal. I am think SSIS is your best bet as you can create a workflow to iterate your reports and send output to various endpoints.